# selecting declared variable value together in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SaveVisitor_info]
    @VisitorName nvarchar(100) = null,
    @VistorCompanyName nvarchar(100) = null,
    @typeofid nvarchar(100) = null,
    @VisitorIDNo nvarchar(100) = null,
    @VisitPurpose nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Company nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Department nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Employee nvarchar(100) = null,
    @passno nvarchar(100) = null,
    @Accompaniedby integer = null,
    @stordloc nvarchar(100) = null,
    @nationality nvarchar(100) = null,
    @occupation nvarchar(100) = null,
    @mobileno nvarchar(100) = null
as 
begin
    declare @idtype integer,
            @visitid integer,
            @cmpid integer,
            @dptid integer,
            @empid integer,
            @currentdate datetime

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    select @currentdate = getdate()

    select @idtype = td.ID 
    from Type_ofID_tbl td 
    where td.IDName = @typeofid

    Select @visitid = v.vistid  
    from VisitPurpose_tbl v 
    where v.purpose = @VisitPurpose

    select @cmpid = c.Cid 
    from CompanyMaster_tbl c 
    where c.CompanyName=@Company

    select @dptid = d.dtId 
    from DepartmentMaster_tbl d 
    where d.dtName = @Department

    select @empid = e.eId 
    from EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    where e.eName = @Employee

    insert into Visitorlogo_tbl(VName, VCompanyName, Idid, IdNo, VisitId, cmpid, Deptid, empid, PassNo, TotalVisitor, 
                                StordLocation, Nationality, Occupation, MobileNo, EntryTime, status)
    values(@VisitorName, @VistorCompanyName, @idtype, @VisitorIDNo, @visitid, @cmpid, @dptid, @empid, @passno, @Accompaniedby,
           @stordloc, @nationality, @occupation, @mobileno, @currentdate, 1)
end
```

This stored procedure works fine and I'm getting the correct output.

I am declaring some variables and getting each variable value. After that I am inserting those values into my table.

I want to know how I can write the stored procedure easier than this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks okay to me, if it works, why try to fix it? Besides, without seeing your database structure, there is no way to improve it into a single select query...

Comment: here i am writting lot of select statement..that will affect my stored procedure speed right?

Comment: If you can show us the relationships between the tables, we may be able to combine your select statements, otherwise you can only do as @Szymon has suggested and write all your variables directly into the insert, although this is purely a visual improvement as the speed gain will be almost nothing.

Comment: You have the wrong priorities! **FIRST** make sure it works and does what it really has to do - only *then*, if system performance is unacceptably bad, start to optimize. Don't overoptimize / optimize before actually seeing an isseu! You'll just waste your time doing unnecessary optimizations....

Comment: sir this stored procedure working fine..i want to optimize,,

Answer (score 1):

This is the most efficient way or writing this. Yes, you had to write five singleton selects on five different tables, so what? -- you might be able to write a single select joining those fove tables, but performance-wise you will gain nothing, just the opposite.

If there's a perf problem, create indexes on columns used in where clause, if they're missing, and include columns from the select list if necessary. But I don't think you'll come to that.